# OpenLDAP invalid credentials immediately after setting credentials

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

I am having trouble binding users that are not the root dn in OpenLDAP, even if I immediately set the password, I still get `ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)`

For example, if I use `ldappasswd` to set the password (authenticating with the root dn), and then immediately use `ldapwhoami` to try to authenticate, I get the following error:

```
leif@nixos ~ $ ldappasswd -x -D cn=Admin,dc=leifandersen,dc=net -W -s badpasswd cn=leiftest,ou=users,dc=leif,dc=net
Enter LDAP Password: 
leif@nixos ~ $ ldapwhoami -x -w badpasswd -D cn=leiftest,ou=users,dc=leifandersen,dc=pl
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

(Note that in this case slapd is running on `localhost` and port `389`, so I don't seem to need to specify those.)

I am using ppolicy, configured as:

```
# ppolicy, leifandersen.net
dn: cn=ppolicy,dc=leifandersen,dc=net
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
objectClass: pwdPolicy
cn: ppolicy
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdExpireWarning: 600
pwdFailureCountInterval: 30
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 5
pwdInHistory: 5
pwdMaxAge: 0
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 5
pwdMustChange: FALSE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
pwdLockoutDuration: 30
pwdLockout: FALSE
```

And set up my initial configuration of OpenLDAP with nix, the relevant bit (I think) being:

```
"olcOverlay=ppolicy" = {
  attrs = {
    objectClass = [ "olcOverlayConfig" "olcPPolicyConfig" ];
    olcOverlay = "ppolicy";
    olcPPolicyDefault = "cn=ppolicy,dc=leif,dc=pl";
    olcPPolicyUseLockout = "FALSE";
    olcPPolicyHashCleartext = "TRUE";
  };
};
```

the whole config being:

```
services.openldap = {
  enable = true;
  settings = {
    attrs.olcLogLevel = [ "stats" ];
    children = {
      "cn=schema".includes = [
        "${pkgs.openldap}/etc/schema/core.ldif"
        "${pkgs.openldap}/etc/schema/cosine.ldif"
        "${pkgs.openldap}/etc/schema/inetorgperson.ldif"
        "${pkgs.openldap}/etc/schema/nis.ldif"
        "${pkgs.openldap}/etc/schema/ppolicy.ldif"
      ];
      "olcDatabase={-1}frontend" = {
        attrs = {
          objectClass = "olcDatabaseConfig";
          olcDatabase = "{-1}frontend";
          olcAccess = [ "{0}to * by dn.exact=uidNumber=0+gidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth manage stop by * none stop" ];
        };
      };
      "olcDatabase={0}config" = {
        attrs = {
          objectClass = "olcDatabaseConfig";
          olcDatabase = "{0}config";
          olcAccess = [ "{0}to * by * none break" ];
        };
      };
      "olcDatabase={1}mdb" = {
        attrs = {
          objectClass = ["olcDatabaseConfig" "olcMdbConfig"];
          olcDatabase = "{1}mdb";
          olcDbDirectory = "/var/db/ldap";
          olcDbIndex = [
          "objectClass eq"
            "cn pres,eq"
            "uid pres,eq"
            "sn pres,eq,subany"
          ];
          olcSuffix = "dc=leifandersen,dc=net";
          olcAccess = [ "{0}to * by * none break" ]; # read break for readable
          olcRootDN = "cn=Admin,dc=leifandersen,dc=net";
          olcRootPW = "{SSHA}<SOMEHASH>";
        };
        children = {
          "olcOverlay=ppolicy" = {
            attrs = {
              objectClass = [ "olcOverlayConfig" "olcPPolicyConfig" ];
              olcOverlay = "ppolicy";
              olcPPolicyDefault = "cn=ppolicy,dc=leif,dc=pl";
              olcPPolicyUseLockout = "FALSE";
              olcPPolicyHashCleartext = "TRUE";
            };
          };
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting an invalid credentials error? Is there something wrong with my ppolicy setup? (I know its not as strict as it should be, I laxed the requirements a bit in the hopes I could get something to work. Also sorry if this is a bad question, I'm still very new to ldap and my previous searches didn't turn up any answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLDAP requires during authentication binds that access be explicitly granted for the necessary attributes (particularly `userPassword`) to be used during authentication by the state of the bind before authentication (i.e. anonymous). Try changing the line

```
          olcAccess = [ "{0}to * by * none break" ]; # read break for readable
```

to

```
          olcAccess = [
            "{0}to attr=userPassword by anonymous auth"
            "{1}to * by * none break"
          ]; # read break for readable
```

in the "{1}mdb" section, as suggested [here](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#ldap_bind:%20Insufficient%20access).